# Assign a list of values to another list using linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to achieve the same code logic using Linq basically or re factoring the code would be great.

```
 List<PublisherDto> listOfMappedPublishers = new List<PublisherDto>();

 listOfPublishers.ForEach(pub =>
 {
     PublisherDto publisher = new PublisherDto();

     publisher.ApiKey = pub.ApiKey;
     publisher.Name = pub.Name;
     publisher.Password = pub.Password;

     listOfMappedPublishers.Add(publisher);
 });

 return listOfMappedPublishers;
```

Comment: What stops you from doing it ? Actually, this question looks like *code for me* which is off-topic

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using .NET Core with C# 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Select` and `ToList` as follow:

```
List<PublisherDto> listOfMappedPublishers = listOfPublishers.Select(i=> new PublisherDto()
{ 
    ApiKey = i.ApiKey,
    Name = i.Name,
    Password  = i.Password
}).ToList();
```

Comment: thankyou so much it looks better now :)

Comment: You are welcome, please mark answer as an accepted by clicking the check-mark, so that it helps the others.

Comment: sure why not :)